# How to show AIX bridge settings

Tags: aix, bridge

While Linux has "brctl show" command, I cannot find any similar for AIX.

Question: How can we show AIX bridge settings?

Comment: Do `lsattr -E -l <device>` or `lsdev`  give any result ? (you have to figure out lsdev opt, I don't have an AIX at hand.

Comment: Is this a theoretical question, or are you dealing with an SEA on a VIO, or something else?

Answer (score 0):

On a VIOS as padmin user, you can show all [SEA](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/POWER7/p7hb1/iphb1_vios_concepts_network_sea.htm?cp=POWER7%2F1-8-3-5-2-4-5) adapters via `lsmap -all -net` and you can see their defined attributes via `lsdev -dev <devicename> -attr`. For the current running configuration, you can see the status and much more via `entstat -all <devicename>`.

For information on how to create a SEA using VIOS command line, see 
[Configuring a Shared Ethernet Adapter with the Virtual I/O Server command-line interface](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/POWER7/p7hb1/iphb1_vios_configuring_sea.htm?cp=POWER7%2F1-8-3-5-7-5-1)

For help on the commands see the VIOS man pages in infocenter

- [lsmap](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/POWER6/iphcg/lsmap.htm)
- [lsdev](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/POWER6/iphcg/lsdev.htm)
- [entstat](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/POWER6/iphcg/entstat.htm)

What are you looking for in particular?